# Reloading multiple child component from parent in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, components, parent-child

I have a problem with reloading my child component from parent component in Angular.

Here is an example of what I want to do.

This is my child component

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  template: `<p> {{ticks}} </p>`,
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  ticks = Date.now().valueOf();

  constructor() {}

  update(): void {
    this.ticks = Date.now().valueOf();
  }
}
```

And here is my parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: false }) childC: ChildComponent;
  showChild: boolean = true;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onUpdateChild() {
    this.childC.update();
  }
}
```

Parent Component HTML :

```
<p>
    parent works!
    <button (click)="onUpdateChild()">update</button>
    <app-child *ngIf="showChild"></app-child>

    <app-child *ngIf="showChild"></app-child>
</p>
```

The main problem is that if I use my child component multiple time, and trying to click on “update” button, it just updates one of my child component that is used in parent component, but I want to update all same child component in parent component, here is what happens when you click on “update” button, only first value will change, not both.

[image]

How can I fix it ?!?

Comment: If you have multiple children, use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild` so that you get a `QueryList` with all children. Then you can run a loop over it and update them. Take a look at the official [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren);

Comment: While the above comment is true, this looks a lot like an Angular anti-pattern. To share data between components, you should either be using data binding, services, or some kind of state management. Calling a child component's method from the parent is, in most cases, a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @ViewChildren and QueryList to do what you are looking for.

`@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childrenC!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;`

And your function would look like:

```
onUpdateChild() { //I would rename it to onUpdateChildren
    if(this.childrenC) { 
       this.childrenC.forEach((childC: ChildComponent) => {
          this.childC.update();
       });
    }
}
```

If you wanted your child component to update on it's own - as stated by a comment to your original post - this is an example of what you could do so you wouldn't even need the update button:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  template: `<p> {{ticks}} </p>`,
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  ticks = Date.now().valueOf();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.ticks = Date.now().valueOf();
    }, 1000); //updates every 1 second
  }
}
```

Another option you can do without using a button is to use `@Input` with the ticks property that updates the value from the parent through an input.